# Getting 503 using websockets on heroku, Custom Domain

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket, apollostack

I'm trying to establish a websocket connection on my heroku node server but keep getting the following error:

```
browser.js:13 WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.mywebsite.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503
```

Works great locally, but when I deploy it to heroku, it's a no go.
I'm running a custom domain in front of my heroku instance and I'm wondering if the dns or something might be causing issues.

Anyone experience something similar?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I too am experiencing this on Heroku, not immediately but within the first few minutes of running my app. Works fine locally.

Comment: In my case I was running a koa node server, and wasn't able to figure how to use websockets on that same server. Instead in my case I opened a new server on a different port. Unfortunately with heroku they only give you 1 open port thats randomly generated. So using another secondary port to accept websockets on heroku is a no go. I ended up using digtal ocean for the time being, until I can figure out how to combine the servers, and have it accept the 2 protocols at the same time. What server are you using?

Comment: I see, sounds like our issues are different then. I am indeed using Heroku, and I use websockets for PouchDB. I had to switch to a different plugin that allows to use the same port for both. At first it works fine, but seems to crash after a few mins.

Comment: Ahh ok gotcha. Unfortunately no experience with pouchdb myself.  Websockets seem frustrating to debug at times. Wish I was more help. Good luck! Let me know what you end up finding out. Could be helpful to others once you nail down the issue.